# Can I use only null in TypeScript (instead of undefined)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, null, undefined

Except for memory save, there is any **functional** reason to use `undefined` in TypeScript?
`null` is more convenient in most situations. For example, when using JSON, only `null` is accepted.

If I need to return something "undefined" in a function, in TypeScript I could return `{ a: 123 }` instead of `{ a: 123, b: undefined }`

There are other reasons to use `undefined` instead of `null` in TypeScript?

Comment: Because you're still writing JavaScript. TypeScript is just a superset, so it needs to contain all of the features of the base.

Comment: JavaScript has `undefined` as a distinct kind of "nothing" along with `null`, so TypeScript really doesn't have much choice.

Comment: Note that one of the few situations in which the `==` comparator is arguably handy and good is that `x == null` will be true when `x` is either `null` or `undefined`, so you rarely have to explicitly test for both if your own code considers them the same.

Comment: So if a write an independent piece of code in TypeScript, could I use only null and I will not lose any functionality of the programming language that I would get using undefined?

Comment: Well yes but note that you can't control what various other APIs will do.